# Default profile in Spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, profiles

In my application I have beans annotated with `@Profile("prod")` and `@Profile("demo")`.
The first one, as you can guess :), is used on beans that connect to production DB and second one annotates beans that use some fake DB (`HashMap` or whatever)- to make development faster.

What I would like to have is default profile (`"prod"`) that will be used always if it is not overridden by "*something-else*".

Perfect would be to have in my `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
     <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and then override this with `-Dspring.profiles.active="demo"` so that I could do:

```
mvn jetty:run -Dspring.profiles.active="demo".
```

But sadly this is not working. Any idea how could I achive that? Setting `-Dspring.profiles.active="prod"` on all my environments  is not an option.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

My experience is that using

```
@Profile("default")
```

the bean will only be added to the context if no other profile is identified. If you pass in a different profile, e.g. `-Dspring.profiles.active="demo"`, this profile is ignored.

Comment: The accepted answer depends on web.xml (and that's fine), but this answer works whether you have web.xml or not and so is more broadly useful to everybody.

Comment: this solution is much cleaner

Comment: @rustyx this is explained in the AbstractEnvironment API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#RESERVED_DEFAULT_PROFILE_NAME
Spring Boot also mentions this behavior by the end of this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-files-profile-specific

Answer (score 111):

Define your production environment as default profile in your web.xml

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
   <param-value>prod</param-value>
</context-param>
```

and if you want to use a different profile pass it as system property

```
mvn -Dspring.profiles.active="demo" jetty:run
```

Comment: No he tried to define the **active** profile in the web.xml and as system property. In my solution I configure a **default** profile in the web.xml and overwrite/define the *active* profile via system property. If there is no explicit *active* profile the default will be used.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I wanted! couldn't find it anywhere :/

Comment: One problem with this approach: if you set `spring.profiles.default=prod` in  `application.properties`, then `application-prod.properties` will not be loaded. This is counter-intuitive.

Comment: @gamliela The approach does not set the default profile in an `application.properties` file. In order to know that `application-prod.properties` should be use you'll have to know the profile. That's what this approach does. It defines profiles outside the spring context either the `web.xml` (default) or via environment variable (overwrite the default).

Comment: @andih Yes, I know that, but I only say it's not intuitive and therefore problematic. Since `application-default.properties` get loaded, I also expect that `application-newdefault.properties` will be loaded as well. It's not a problem with your solution, it's a problem with Spring...

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue, but I use [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) in order to configure the ServletContext programmatically (Servlet 3.0+). So I do the following:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        // Default active profiles can be overridden by the environment variable 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE'
        rootContext.getEnvironment().setDefaultProfiles("prod");
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also consider removing the PROD profile, and use @Profile("!demo")

Comment: I suppose this would not work in case you have more than two profiles, right?

Answer (score 3):

About setting default production profile already posted @andih

The easiest way to set default profile for maven jetty plugin, is to include below element in your plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
            <systemProperty>
                <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                <value>demo</value>
            </systemProperty>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring provide two separate properties when determining which profiles are active:

- `spring.profiles.active`

and

- `spring.profiles.default`

If `spring.profiles.active` is set, then its value determines which profiles are active. But if `spring.profiles.active` isn't set, then Spring looks to `spring.profiles.default.`

If neither `spring.profiles.active` nor `spring.profiles.default` is set, then there are no active profiles, and only those beans that aren't defined as being in a profile are created.Any bean that does not specify a profile belongs to `default` profile.

Answer (score -1):

You can setup your web.xml as filtered resource and have this value filled by maven from maven profile settings - that what we do.

in pom filter all resources (you can do taht if you have no ${} marking in them)

```
<webResources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</webResources>
```

in web.xml put

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
     <param-value>${spring.prfile}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

in pom create maven profiles

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>DEFAULT</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile>prod</spring.profile>
        </properties>
    <profile>
    <profile>
        <id>DEMO</id>
        <properties>
            <spring.profile>demo</spring.profile>
        </properties>
    <profile>
</profiles>
```

Now you can use

```
mvn jetty:run -P DEMO
```

or simply `-P DEMO` with any maven command

Comment: I am not sure but I think that won't work. IMHO jetty:run will not  run phase in which resources are filtered.

Comment: of caurse you need to run mvn clean compile jetty:run -P DEMO, but with uncompiled code it runs it autimaticly

Comment: I understand that one of the main goals of Spring 3.1 Profiles is to generate a single WAR file ready to be deployed in all environments. Using Maven profiles is an step back to the previous state: where the packaging of a WAR file was needed for each environment...

Comment: @edrabc he was asking for mvn jetty:run - there is no WAR file.

Comment: Agree @Hurda. But he was also asking for running the command in multiple environments: having a mix of Maven Profiles and Spring Profiles could be a bit misleading...