# Spring Profile doesn't work with Default active profile

Tags: spring, profile

I am trying to activate spring profile in my application.To do so,

**i have added one parameter in web.xml to activate the default profile.**

```
<context-param>
<param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
<param-value>dev</param-value>
<context-param>
```

This my jdbc file which manipulates the properties. 
           **and my jdbc.context.xml file is**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">    
    <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/classes/jdbc.properties" /> <!-- TODO: config for different profiles, http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/spring-31-profiles-and-tomcat.html -->
     <beans profile="dev">
        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
            </bean>
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource">
                <ref bean="dataSource" />
            </property>
            <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.i2sm.common" />
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
  </beans>
</beans>
```

**But when i restart my Tomcat server, it throws me following exception**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun Dec 23 00:57:22 GMT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:337)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1030)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:993)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:548)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

    Any Suggestion?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify `spring.profiles.default` as the `context-param` instead of `spring.profiles.active`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>dev</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041410/default-profile-in-spring-3-1) and [refer this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-profiles-and-java).

Comment: BUt annotation profile("dev") doesnt work in class? any suggestion