# How to specify the default profile that beans will be registered under in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Given:

```
<beans ... namespace decelerations>
     <bean id="foo" class="com.example.foo" />
     <beans profile="abc">
         <bean id="bar" class="com.exmaple.bar" />
     </beans>
</bean>
```

what is the name of the profile that foo is registered under? Is there a way to override foo in another profile definition? Is there a name for the default profile in spring when a profile is not explicitly specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default profile in Spring 3.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041410/default-profile-in-spring-3-1)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Default profile in spring is "default", see this: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8203

You can change the default profile in web.xml by doing this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Command line:

```
-Dspring.profiles.default=production
```

Env variable:

```
export spring_profiles_default=production
```

If active profile is set, it overrides the default.

Answer (score 5):

`Foo` is simply registered under no profile, it will always be instantiate regardless of the profile you are using in that environment. `Spring` only allow to create multiple beans within an `XML` file with the same `id` if they are in different `<beans>` sets so I don't think that is possible to overwrite the `Foo` bean if it is not inside a `<beans>` tag with a profile.

If no profile are defined, Spring will use the profile named `default`. But, a `bean` that is not inside a `<beans>` tag with a profile will not be registered under that profile. It only means that if you have something like the following `XML` and that no profiles are provided, beans with the default profile will be loaded as well as beans with no profile.

```
<beans ... namespace decelerations>
     <bean id="foo" class="com.example.foo" />
     <beans profile="default">
         <bean id="bar" class="com.exmaple.bar" />
     </beans>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for this: "If no profile are defined, Spring will use the profile named default. " ?

Comment: AbstractEnvironment and subclasses now register a reserved default
    profile named literally 'default' such that with no action on the part
    of the user, beans defined against the 'default' profile will be
    registered - if no other profiles are explicitly activated. https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8203