# Multiple negated profiles

Tags: java, spring

My problem is that I have application, which uses Spring profiles. Building application on server means that the profile is set to "`wo-data-init`". For other build there is "`test`" profile. When any of them is activated they are not supposed to run the Bean method, so I though this annotation should work:

```java
@Profile({"!test","!wo-data-init"})
```

It seems more like it's running `if(!test OR !wo-data-init)` and in my case I need it to run `if(!test AND !wo-data-init)` - is it even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring 4 has brought some cool features for [conditional bean creation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-conditional). In your case, indeed plain `@Profile` annotation is not enough because it uses `OR` operator.

One of the solutions you can do is to create your custom annotation and custom condition for it. For example

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
@Conditional(NoProfilesEnabledCondition.class)
public @interface NoProfilesEnabled {
    String[] value();
}
```

```
public class NoProfilesEnabledCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        boolean matches = true;

        if (context.getEnvironment() != null) {
            MultiValueMap<String, Object> attrs = metadata.getAllAnnotationAttributes(NoProfileEnabled.class.getName());
            if (attrs != null) {
                for (Object value : attrs.get("value")) {
                    String[] requiredProfiles = (String[]) value;

                    for (String profile : requiredProfiles) {
                        if (context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles(profile)) {
                            matches = false;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }
}
```

Above is quick and dirty modification of [ProfileCondition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ProfileCondition.java).

Now you can annotate your beans in the way:

```
@Component
@NoProfilesEnabled({"foo", "bar"})
class ProjectRepositoryImpl implements ProjectRepository { ... }
```

Answer (score 34):

In Spring 5.1.4 (Spring Boot 2.1.2) and above it is as easy as:

```
@Component
@Profile("!a & !b")
public class MyComponent {}
```

Ref: [How to conditionally declare Bean when multiple profiles are not active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429168/how-to-conditionally-declare-bean-when-multiple-profiles-are-not-active/52860023)

Answer (score -3):

I found a better solution

```
@Profile("default")
```

Profile default means no foo and no bar profiles.

Comment: Related to my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041410/default-profile-in-spring-3-1