# get actual spring profile inside WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: java, spring, initialization, spring-profiles

I have the following  entry in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
     <param-value>test</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

and following WebInitializer:

```
public class H2Starter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        if (ArrayUtils.contains(rootContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles(), "test")) {
            System.out.println("test profile is active");
        }
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
    }
}
```

When I start application with test profile (`mvn clean install jetty:run` -Dspring.profiles.active=test) - execution goes into if statement and I see result in console.

If I start application without explicit profile (`mvn clean install jetty:run`) - execution doesn't go into if statement. It is wrong from my side.
P.S. I tried to execute `rootContext.getEnvironment().getDefaultProfiles()` but it returns single element array with value `default`(should be `test` according my opinion)

How to fix this?

Comment: Checkout [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041410/default-profile-in-spring-3-1/10041835#10041835) for more information.

Comment: I don't know why your `getDefaultProfiles()` is showing `default` instead of `test`, but I do think you should be doing `rootContext.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles("test")` instead of  `ArrayUtils.contains(rootContext.getEnvironment().getActiveProfiles(), "test")`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the:

```
  <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

OR you can try do add it as init param for the DispatcherServlet, like this:

```
 <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
          <param-value>test</param-value>
      </init-param>
  </servlet>
```