# How should I test a method with an aspect around?

Tags: spring, integration-testing, spring-aop

I'm trying to do an integration test. These are my components:

**UsersService**

```
@ManageSession
public List<T> get() {
    //...
    return something;
}
```

**ManageSessionAspect**

```
@Autowired
AuthService authService;

@Before("manageSessionMethod()") //methods annotated with @ManageSession
public void doSomething() {
    authService.doSomething();
}
```

I need to test `UsersService.get()` method. But I want to disable the aspect OR I want to be able to mock the `AuthService` inside it.

I have tried using an `is()` pointcut, but I get:

> if() pointcut designator isn't supported by Spring.

Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for **spring profiles**. You can define profiles and tie your configuration classes to these profiles. A configuration tied to a profile will only get activated if the profile is active. See my answer on a related question for further details: [A: How to mock bean and avoiding NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844855/2699901). You will need to define a profile (eg.: test or integration-test) and use that profile in a configuration class to provide a mock implementation for your `AuthService`.

As a side note, I would strongly suggest you go with AspectJ  (preferably compile-time weaving) instead of Spring AOP as it's much more powerful.